# OSGI - How to solve: ClassNotFoundException? (org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass)

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle, classnotfoundexception

When using three bundles A = **first.bundle** B = **second.bundle** and C = **third.bundle**, where A depends on B and C, C is not able to find a class of B when calling the method *java.lang.Class.forName*

Is there a missing configuration in any pom.xml file or any other way to equip the ClassLoader of the bunlde C with the class B.SecondClass?

org.example.first.bundle.FirstClass

```java
public void topLevelMethod() {
  ThirdClass thirdObject = new ThirdClass();
  thirdObject.resolveTheClassName("org.example.second.bundle.SecondClass")
}
```

org.example.third.bundle.ThirdClass

```java
public <T> Class<T> resolveTheClassName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
  return (Class<T>) Class.forName(className);
}
```

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.second.bundle.SecondClass cannot be found by third.bundle_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
> at org.example.third.bundle.ThirdClassA.getContentType(ThirdClassA.java:100)
> at org.example.third.bundle.ThirdClassB$ReceivingTask.run(ThirdClassB.java:135)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

first.bundle/pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>second.package</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>third.package</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependencies>
```

second.bundle/pom.xml

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Import-Package>
                        *;resolution:=optional
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        org.example.second.bundle
                    </Export-Packlage>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

third.bundle/pom.xml

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Import-Package>
                        *;resolution:=optional
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        org.example.third.bundle
                    </Export-Packlage>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class loaders are configured in a graph with edges for each package imported. So if C does not have an import edge for a package in B, then C cannot class load a class from that package in B.

If C has an object from B, it could use the class loader for the class of the object from B in the Class.forName call. But generally one should not be using Class.forName in OSGi. It would be better to use OSGi services. Then C can locate interesting objects in the OSGi service registry.

Comment: Thank you, I did research on a native OSGI approach and found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

```java
public <T> Class<T> resolveTheClassName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
  BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
        List<Class<?>> foundClasses = findClass(bundleContext, serializedContentType);
        if(foundClasses.isEmpty()) {
            return (Class<T>)Class.forName(serializedContentType);
        } else {
            return (Class<T>)foundClasses.get(0);
        }
}
```

```java
private List<Class<?>> findClass(BundleContext context, String name) {
    List<Class<?>> result = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    for (Bundle b : context.getBundles()) {
        try {
            Class<?> c = b.loadClass(name);
            result.add(c);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // No problem, this bundle doesn't have the class
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

> [How to load a class by classname string from OSGi runtime environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010763/how-to-load-a-class-by-classname-string-from-osgi-runtime-environment)